How can I fix the !Missing number... error on documentclass{facsimile}?
I had a facsimile template using documentclass{facsimile} that stopped working with a !Missing number error flagged on the line with \makefaxtitle. So, I attempted to compile the example given with the package and got the same error with detail \maxfr@meheight=\dimen149 (though on my template fax with different \faxto and \faxfrom the detail was \maxfr@meheight=\dimen154.
I am using texmaker 6.0.0 with TeX Live Utility 1.54 and all packages updated. I don't know how to proceed when the example won't even compile. (Admittedly, this package is 20 years old.)
Below is the example I used.
\documentclass{facsimile} 
\faxsubject{Curriculum vitae}
\faxto{%
 \begin{tabular}{rl}   
 to: & \textbf{The President}\\   
 fax: & +1-202-456-1414\\   
 \end{tabular}}   
\faxfrom{%
 \begin{tabular}{rl}
 from: & Bugs Bunny\\
 address: & ACME Street 42\\
 & 90210 Toontown\\
 & USA\\
 phone/fax: & +1-555-314159\\
 \end{tabular}}

\begin{document}    
 \makefaxtitle   
   
 \opening{Dear Mr.President,}   
   
 I submit my curriculum vitae as arranged by phone.   
   
 [\dots]
   
 \closing{Yours most sincerely}   
   
\end{document}

Thank you for looking at this.

you could try to get the package updated to match the new (copied from hyperref) \pageref structure.  Failing that you can roll latex back to 2020.

\RequirePackage[2020/01/01]{latexrelease}
\documentclass{facsimile} 
\faxsubject{Curriculum vitae}
\faxto{%
 \begin{tabular}{rl}   
 to: & \textbf{The President}\\   
 fax: & +1-202-456-1414\\   
 \end{tabular}}   
\faxfrom{%
 \begin{tabular}{rl}
 from: & Bugs Bunny\\
 address: & ACME Street 42\\
 & 90210 Toontown\\
 & USA\\
 phone/fax: & +1-555-314159\\
 \end{tabular}}


\begin{document}

 \makefaxtitle   
   
 \opening{Dear Mr.President,}   
   
 I submit my curriculum vitae as arranged by phone.   
   
 [\dots]
   
 \closing{Yours most sincerely}   
   
\end{document}


The class expects that \r@LastPage (when it's defined) expands to something like {}{n}, where n is the last page number.
But with newer kernels it expands to {}{n}{}{}{}.
Solution: change the outdated method to get the page number from \r@LastPage.
\documentclass{facsimile} 

\makeatletter
\ifdefined\@secondoffive
\renewcommand*{\@lstpgno}{%
  \@ifundefined{r@LastPage}{0}{%
    \expandafter\@secondoffive\r@LastPage
  }%
}
\fi
\makeatother

\faxsubject{Curriculum vitae}
\faxto{%
 \begin{tabular}{rl}   
 to: & \textbf{The President}\\   
 fax: & +1-202-456-1414\\   
 \end{tabular}}   
\faxfrom{%
 \begin{tabular}{rl}
 from: & Bugs Bunny\\
 address: & ACME Street 42\\
 & 90210 Toontown\\
 & USA\\
 phone/fax: & +1-555-314159\\
 \end{tabular}}

\begin{document}

\makefaxtitle   
   
\opening{Dear Mr.President,}   
   
 I submit my curriculum vitae as arranged by phone.   
   
 [\dots]
   
 \closing{Yours most sincerely}   
   
\end{document}

If you don't plan to use older versions of LaTeX, you can remove the \ifdefined line and the matching \fi.

